# How to treat a y when deriving a function?

Tags: calculus

My econ class gave these questions.
Find derivatives for the following functions:
$$g(z) = z + y + 15$$
$$f(z) = yz + 2y$$

I'm not sure how I should treat the $y$. Is it a function or a variable?

If it is a variable $g'(z)=2$ and $f'(z)=y+2$ but as a function $g'(z)=1+y'$ and $f'(z)=zy'+y+2y'$.

Comment: Is this derivative supposed to be a *partial derivative*?  The fact that you have $g(z)$ and $f(z)$ instead of $g(y,z)$ and $f(y,z)$ makes me guess that $y$ might just be a constant.  But without context there's no way for us to tell for sure.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, the verb form of "derivative" is "differentiate" not "derive". You take some formulas and theorems and "derive" another formula or theorem. You "differentiate" a function to find its derivative.

To answer your question, it depends on what you're taking the derivative with respect to. Since you write $g(z)$, it is safe to assume that $y$ is a constant and may be treated as such. Thus you treat $y$ like it was any number.

Comment: This is why in most cases I prefer Leibniz's notation. I thought it clunky at first, but I find it makes it easier to follow the process of differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here. Either $z$ is a variable and $y$ is a constant, or $z=x+iy$.

In that case,

$g'(z)=1$

$f'(z)=y$.

I think that would be the case given the course you are taking.

My answer is also assuming we are differentiating w.r.t to $z$.